# Determinant if Two Rows Are Equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

What is the reasoning that the determinant will be zero if two rows are exactly the same? I see a lot of pseudo proofs out there for this one and would like to know the reasoning behind it.

Comment: How much do you know about determinant?

Comment: It depends. It's a bit tough to do using the calculation of the determinant directly. Therefore, instead of saying "the determinant of $A$ is $0$", one uses one of the equivalent conditions given in the [invertible matrix theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem). Some examples are "The equation $Ax = 0$ has more than one solution", or "The rows of $A$ are linearly dependent" (technically that one isn't listed there, but one point says the same about the columns, and one says that there is no difference between $A$ and $A^T$ in this respect).

Comment: A lot. I'm familiar with levi civita, laplace, sign of a determinant, etc. but I'm curious about this.

Comment: Well a  determinant is an *alternating n-linear form*, so...

Comment: Is there any intuition you know as to why the invertible matrix theorem holds true? Particularly for this reason?

Comment: @Will It's all intuitive once you've used it enough. Until then, every single thing on that list is proven separately, more or less, so no.

Comment: I was wanting to know specifically when two rows are equivalent in a matrix, then why the determinant is 0 (not everything on that list). I appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Theorem:** for two $n\times n$ matrices of the same size, $A$ and $B$, one has $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ (*not proven here*)

**Theorem:** Elementary row operations can be described via left multiplication by elementary matrices.  More specifically, the row operation $r_i+kr_j\mapsto r_i$ is described by the matrix with ones along the diagonal and $k$ in the $i^{th}$ row $j^{th}$ column position.  For example, in a $4\times 4$ matrix, doing the operation $r_3-r_4\mapsto r_3$ is accomplished by $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&-1\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

**Theorem:** The previously described elementary matrix for row addition has determinant one.  This is seen immediately by the fact that there is only ever one nonzero pattern in the matrix, namely the main diagonal.

---

**Result:** If you have a square matrix $A$ and you wish to compute its determinant, you may add or subtract multiples of rows from other rows and it will not change its determinant since $\det(A)=\det(E)\det(A)=\det(EA)$ for elementary matrices that apply this row summation operation.  If this happens to cause a row of all zeroes to appear, it immediately implies that the determinant will be zero as every pattern in the matrix will have to take an entry from that row and the product will necessarily be zero in that case.

Note: other elementary row operations effect a change to the determinant.  Row swaps will flip the sign of the determinant from positive to negative or vice versa.  Row multiplication by a constant $k$ will multiply the resulting determinant by the same constant $k$.

---

Another quick way to see this is via the invertible matrix theorem.  Among the *many* items on the list for the invertible matrix theorem is:

An $n\times n$ matrix has nonzero determinant iff the matrix is invertible iff its rows form a linearly independent set.

If two rows are equal, they are linearly **dependent**, implying they do not form a linearly independent set, implying the matrix is not invertible, implying the determinant is zero.

Comment: I think that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Actually, that is what I'm looking for:) I appreciate your time (very thorough).

Answer (score 0):

One way to prove this is by the Rank-Nullity Theorem. This states that for any $n$ by $n$ matrix $A$ $$ \mathrm{dim} (\mathrm{null}(A)) + \mathrm{rank}(A) = n$$

If two rows of A are linearly dependent, A does not have full rank $n$. Therefore, $$\mathrm{dim} (\mathrm{null}(A)) > 0$$

This in turn implies that $\mathrm{det}(A) = 0$.